# How to create a small secondary tile in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
 SecondaryTile secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                                            "Title text shown on the tile",
                                                            tileActivationArguments,
                                                            square150x150Logo,
                                                            TileSize.Square150x150);
```

If I try to do a different size secondary tile it throws an exception. Can you actually make it small? By small I mean quarter of the regular square tile size.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a static method that I use to create secondary tiles. You set the image for both sizes of image.  The Uri in ShellTile.Create defines what page in your application will load when the secondary tile is pressed.

```
    internal static void CreateSecondaryTile(string title, Uri imageUrl)
    {
        FlipTileData secondaryTile = new FlipTileData()
        {
            Title = "my Title", 
            BackgroundImage = imageUrl,
            SmallBackgroundImage = imageUrl
        };

        ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/WebPagePage.xaml?selectedURL=" +
                title , UriKind.Relative), secondaryTile, false);
    }
```

Comment: I don't mean the size of image within a tile, but the size of the live tile itself.

Comment: Yes so do I. Using my answer you simply define the image to be used in the live tile for each of the sizes in this case (normal and small). When the size of the tile is manipulated by the user on their home screen, the corresponding image will be shown?